# Symfony2 SonataAdminBundle Google Chrome ERR_RESPONSE_HEADERS_TOO_BIG

Tags: php, google-chrome, sonata-admin, symfony-2.2

Using Syfony 2.2 in dev environment, trying to display a list view of the SonataAdminBundle. 
I'm getting Error 325 / **ERR_RESPONSE_HEADERS_TOO_BIG** in Google Chrome. No problems in Safari and Firefox. This only happens in the dev environment and on every list view, edit views are ok.

Checked the headers via curl, seems fine:

```
curl -I http://project.local/app_dev.php/admin/project/site/user/list

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sat, 23 Mar 2013 22:47:37 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.24 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.24 OpenSSL/1.0.1e DAV/2 PHP/5.3.22
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.22
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=hgfp4kdmjtl9neodli2d83e1i0; path=/
Cache-Control: no-cache
X-Debug-Token: 514e3109e09ae
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

Disabled XDebug and APC, but no change there.
Thanks a lot for any pointers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check in your config_dev.yml for following lines and comment them.

```
#chrome:
 #type:  chromephp
 #level: info
```

Why do you get this error?
It enables support of some sort of debugger for chrome like firephp in firefox... 
http://www.chromephp.com/

Problem is that the response header is too big to print out the info because of a configuration setting on your server. If you increase the allowed size in your server config the problem will also disappear.